# Retrieving a url (or any value) from SPList

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I just spent half an hour trying to figure out how to retrieve a link from SPList.

I have a column of type "Hyperlink or Picture" in a list, and so far I came up with this:

```
SPListItem item = /* init item here */
SPFieldUrl field = item.Fields["URL"] as SPFieldUrl;
SPFieldUrlValue urlValue = field.GetFieldValue(item["URL"].ToString()) as SPFieldUrlValue;
string url = urlValue.Url;
```

This is ugly, though - is there a better way ?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Development (hell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a tad cleaner way:

```
SPListItem item = /* init item here */
string url = new SPFieldUrlValue(item["URL"].ToString()).Url;
```

Comment: Be careful when item["URL"] is null!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value directly from the item rather than converting it.  Example:

```
SPListItem item = //whatever
string url = item["URL"].ToString();
```

Comment: No, that would return something like "Pageurl,PageName"